# How to check column value null or having value

Tags: ios, sql, if-statement, case, inner-join

I need to check, if the column is null it will take null. And if the column is having some value i need to get value from that column. I tried IF statement and CASE but it's not working. I'm using this query for iOS sqlite.

```
select 
b.QM_ID,b.QM_QCM_ID,b.QM_Question,b.QM_Type,b.QM_Parent_Id,null,null 
from question_master b INNER JOIN Assessment_master d
```

Table:

```
b.QM_ID b.QM_QCM_ID  b.QM_Question d.AM_Answer d.AM_Comments
   3       2             question     NULL        value
   4        5             question2    NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does have an ISNULL() function. However, it works a little bit different from Microsoft's ISNULL() function.

In MySQL we can use the IFNULL() function, like this:

```
SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice*(UnitsInStock+IFNULL(UnitsOnOrder,0))
FROM Products
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: IFNULL(d.AM_Answer,0)